# Android How to update a TextView within a ListView's HeaderView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that I add a headerView as below. When the user clicks a button, I attempt to update a TextView that is inside the ListView's header View

```
if(mHeaderView == null){
    mHeaderView = (LinearLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_report, listViewReports, false);
}

TextView textViewName = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.report_header_name);
textViewName.setText(student.getFullName();
```

**The TextView only updates if the TextView changes size** - for example if the student.getFullName() returns a longer name causing the textView to wrap to another line.

I have tried invalidating `textViewName` and `mHeaderView`. Also I have tried having `textViewName` as a class variable. Neither have worked.

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Store reference to the header text that was originally used when creating the Header. Then just call the `setText` when needed.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me. I store both the mHeaderView and textViewName as class variables But the textView text is not updated.

Comment: Would it then be easier to manually create a header Textview. Place a textview above the listview and set it to the same dimensions as the Listview content?

Comment: Not in this case because, I need the text view to scroll away with the listview.